# JavaScript two equal Date with different day

Tags: javascript

I'm using method getDay() from Date() to get day of the week, then I notice that the same Date without time returns me a different day of the week

```
new Date().getDay()
```

this first one returns me **3**

```
new Date('2017-09-27').getDay()
```

this one returns me **2**

Comparing these results with some friends I notice that almost everyone had different results, even worse, some people really got day 26 when the date 27 was written

I'm almost sure this problem is caused by timezone issues but I can't find how get accurate results

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is when you pass the date `2017-09-27` into the date method you have not passed a timezone in. Look at the results below:

```
> new Date()
Wed Sep 27 2017 12:58:39 GMT-0700 (PDT)
> new Date('2017-09-27')
Tue Sep 26 2017 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

You can pass your time zone in for example in PDT (GMT-08:00)

```
> new Date('2017-09-27 GMT-08:00')
Wed Sep 27 2017 01:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

Or you can use a library like [moment](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: This hints at but does not really answer the question. OP already knows time zones are involved somehow.

Comment: @msanford I have updated the answer, let me know if you need more.

Comment: Yes, it is what I thought. I notice if setting date as new Date('September 27, 2017') there is no issues, and both had same amount of information. Is this a javascript bug?

Comment: Not a bug, just inconsistency, using "YYYY-MM-DD" format it assumes UTC timezone (which is then converted to your local timezone where the day doesn't match), while giving "Month DD, YYYY" uses your local timezone. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Differences_in_assumed_time_zone